# Div content alignment

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a dynamically generated div.
I have to add a dynamically generated HTML table on it.

The problem is when I'm add the table, it display as left aligned.
  But the div is center aligned for text contents.

Comment: will you paste your code?

Comment: I see asp.net tag, so please paste only rendered html/css, not the asp.net markup

Comment: have you check in other browsers, paste your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have your table as a fixed width element, you can set margin-left/right to auto to center a block element in it's container. (Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SWakJ/)

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
    <table id="tab">
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tab {
    border:solid 1px black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:2px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add some css to your outer div.

I actually wrote a similar answer here:
[Position this div in the center of it's container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376530/position-this-div-in-the-center-of-its-container/15377064#15377064)

Answer (score 0):

Give your code or just go quick to your code and check this. Put a div above table and set text-align= center. or if your table is in any td then assign text-align:center.

Also you can put  tag and put table between it.

If you want to just center the table column than also provide text-align:center

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about your code but as per problem this could help you.

```
function makeTable() {

row=new Array();
cell=new Array();

row_num=12; //edit this value to suit
cell_num=12; //edit this value to suit
tab=document.createElement('table');
tab.setAttribute('id','newtable');
tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
for(c=0;c<row_num;c++){
row[c]=document.createElement('tr');
for(k=0;k<cell_num;k++) {
cell[k]=document.createElement('td');
cont=document.createTextNode((c+1)*(k+1))
cell[k].appendChild(cont);
row[c].appendChild(cell[k]);
}
tbo.appendChild(row[c]);
}
tab.appendChild(tbo);
document.getElementById('mytable').appendChild(tab);
}
```

the you can set allignment through CSS as below:

```
#newtable{
border:2px solid #999;
font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
margin:auto;
}
#newtable td{
width:50px;
line-height:50px;
border:1px solid #000;
text-align:center;
}
```

or see this link "http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3614377.htm"

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
<div id="div1">
 <table id="tab">
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
 #div1
{
  width:500px;
  text-align:center;
}
#tab {
  border:solid 1px black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin:2px auto;
}
#tab td
{
  /*  width: 200px;
   text-align:center;*/ 
}
```

Running Demo [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SWakJ/1/)